# Multi threading script favors .start() which is first and doesn't run the others at all python

Tags: python, multithreading

So this is a snippet from my script (the main one has 10 scripts that need to be run, here I am just testing with two)

```
#parent.py

from threading import Thread
import sys

sys.path.append('/python/loanrates/BTC')
sys.path.append('/python/loanrates/ETH')


import BTC
import ETH

t5 = Thread(target=ETH.main())
t1 = Thread(target=BTC.main())

t5.start()
t1.start()
```

Which ever `tx.start()` is first is the script that is run and the one below doesn't. I'm quite new to multi threading, it was actually working earlier with two then I tried with all 10, it didn't work went back to two and now that doesn't work either, any help would be appreciated.

Ps here is a sample to one of the child scripts http://pastebin.com/bxzdNeYp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread target should be callable - without ():

```
t = Thread(target=my_function)
```

to wait for execution of all threads, you need to use `join`, which waits for the thread execution. In your code:

```
t5.join()
t1.join()
```

if you have many threads, simply store them into array and then loop over the array and call `join` on each thread